# "No editor descriptor" error after CUDA plugin installation + Eclipse update

Tags: eclipse, cuda, nsight, version-compatibility

I had installed the CUDA 10 Eclipse plugin via my installed Ecplise's UI. Later on, I updated Eclipse to version 2020.09. Now, when I try to open a `.cu` file, I get an error saying:

```
No editor descriptor for id com.nvidia.cuda.ui.editor.CudaEditor
```

With the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.Exception
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createErrorPart(EditorReference.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPart(CompatibilityEditor.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:338)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.createElement(PartServiceImpl.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1266)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$9(WorkbenchPage.java:3102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3100)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3070)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3061)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenFileAction.openFile(OpenFileAction.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenSystemEditorAction.run(OpenSystemEditorAction.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$1.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1118)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5745)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1427)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5013)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4507)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

How can I avoid this error and just make the `.cu` file open normally?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why I got this problem, but here's how I've overcome it:

1. On the menus, navigate to **Window | Preferences**
2. In the preferences dialog, navigate to **General | Content Types**
3. In the content type tree, navigate to **Text > C Source File > C++ Source File** and click it
4. Near the file association box, click <kbd>Add...</kbd>
5. Type `*.cu` in the dialog box and press Enter.
6. Exit the preferences dialog, close the .cu file and open it again.

That should do it.

You can do the same for `.cuh` files under **Text > C Source File > C++ Source File > C++ Header File**.